# Printing char arrays c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I was playing around with c strings in c++ and found some behavior I don't understand when I don't terminate a `char` array.

```
char strA[2] = {'a','\0'};
char strB[1] = {'b'};
cout << strA << strB;
```

I would expect this to print `ab`, but instead it prints `aba`. If I instead declare `strB` before `strA`, it works as expected. Could someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: You're at the mercy of how things are laid out on the stack by the compiler. The `strA` is beling placed later in memory (i.e. earlier in the stack) than `strB`. The strings are adjacent in memory, so when you print the non-terminated `strB` it continues on, printing `strA` as well before hitting the `\0` in `strA`.

Comment: Undefined behavior.

Comment: You are playing with char arrays, not with C strings.

Comment: When outputting an array of char (which it receives as a pointer), `cout`s `operator<<()` - like most C I/O functions - ASSUMES there is a terminating zero present, and keeps going until it finds it.    If there is no terminator, the result is undefined behaviour - anything can happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happened when we do not include '\0' at the end of string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995106/what-happened-when-we-do-not-include-0-at-the-end-of-string-in-c)

Comment: [why printf works on non-terminated string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4999901/995714), [String is longer than expected in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33707486/995714)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is *undefined behaviour* and you simply are lucky that replacing the declaration of these 2 arrays works for you. Let's see what is happening in your code:

```
char strA[2] = {'a','\0'};
```

Creates an array that can be treated like a string - it is **null terminated**.

```
char strB[1] = {'b'};
```

Creates an array that **cannot** be treated like a string, because it lacks the null terminating character `'\0'`.

---

```
std::cout << strA << strB;
```

The first part, being `<< strA`, works fine. It prints `a` since `strA` is treated as a `const char*`, which provided as an argument for `std::ostream& operator <<` will be used to print every character untill the **null terminating character is encountered**.

What happens then? Then, the `<< strB` is being executed (*actually what happens here is a little different and more complicated than simply dividing this line into two, separate `std::cout <<` calls, but it does not matter here*). It is also treated as a `const char*`, **which is expected to ended with mentioned `'\0'`**, however it is not...

What does that lead to? You are lucky enough that there randomly is only 1 character before (again - random) `'\0'` in memory, which stops the (possibly near-infinite) printing process.

---

> Why, if I instead declare `strB` before `strA`, it works as expected?

That is because you were lucky enough that the compiler decided to declare your `strA` just after the `strB`, thus, when printing the `strB`, it prints everything that it consists + prints `strA`, which ends with null terminating character. This is not guaranteed. Avoid using `char[]` to represent and print strings. Use `std::string` instead, which takes care of the null terminating character for you.

Answer (score 0):

When printing char arrays, the `C` (and `C++`) convention is to print all bytes until a '\0'.

Because of how the local variables are organized, `strB`'s memory is behind `strA`'s, so when printing `strB` the printing just 'overflows' and keeps printing `strA` until the terminating '\0'.

I guess when the deceleration is reversed, the printing of `strB` is terminated by a `0` that is just there because nothing else was set there, but you shouldn't rely on that - this is called a garbage value.

Don't use unterminated C-strings, **at all**. Also avoid C-strings in general, you can use `C++` `std::string` which are much more secure and fun.

When I run this code on my computer, I have a bunch (exactly seven) of weird chars printed between the `ab` to the `a`, which are probably whatever was between `strA`'s and `strB`'s memory spaces.
When I reverse the declarations, I get `ab$%^&` where `$%^&` are a bunch of weird chars - the ones between the end of `strB`'s memory to the next random `\0`.