# why the program prints in first loop with the wanted array the other array and in second loop prints targeted array with extra variable character?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    char x[3]={'a','b','c'} , y[3]={'e','f','j'};
```

// first loop  here it prints the elements of the targeted array with the elements of the other array in each loop .

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 20 ;i++)
    {
        cout << y ;
    }
    cout << "\n\n" ;
```

//second loop prints the elements of targeted array with extra variable character each loop .

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 20 ;i++)
    {
        cout << x ;
    }

    return (0) ;
}
```

Comment: `cout << y` exhibits undefined behavior, as `y` is not NUL-terminated. So does `cout << x`. Both expressions call `operator<<(const char*)` overload, which expects a pointer to a NUL-terminated string.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46507641/printing-char-arrays-c).

Comment: Be careful with `using namespace std;` ([Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)) and don't use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` ([Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)). Definitely do not use them together; it turns your code into a minefield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the or all api looks for the null terminated character when the prints the char array. So `'\0'` must be added at the end of char array. Which will effectively increase the array size by `1`.

So the correct program will be like below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char x[4]={'a','b','c', '\0'} , y[4]={'e','f','j', '\0'};

    for (int i = 0; i < 20 ;i++)
    {
        cout << y <<endl;
    }
    cout << "\n\n" ;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20 ;i++)
    {
        cout << x <<endl;
    }
    return (0) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To print a character using `cout` or `printf` null terminated string is required. You have declared the character array as string which is not null terminated.

Change the line with null terminated char, then it will print properly.

```
char x[4]={'a','b','c','\0'} , y[4]={'e','f','j','\0'};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used `char x[4] = "abc";` (note number of elements in the array) then

> After any necessary concatenation, in translation phase 7 (5.2), ’\0’ is appended to every string literal **so that programs that scan a string can find its end**.

and so length of `x` would be 4:

> The size of a narrow string literal is the total number of escape sequences and other characters, plus at least one for the multibyte encoding of each universal - character - name, plus one for the terminating ’\0’.

But if you want to use an array, you need to provide '\0' explicitly:

```
char x[4]={'a','b','c','\0'} , y[4]={'e','f','j','\0'};
```

See [[lex.string]](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.string) for more info.