# Can't create integer array to hold characters

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new to programming and started to learn c few weeks back. I have read in a book that character array should end with `\0`, but when i create an array without `\0`, it works properly. How is it possible.?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char a[] = {'a','p','p','l','e'};

    printf("%d\n",strlen(a));
    printf("%s\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code output is

> ```
> 5
> apple
> ```

Also I read that char is a subset of integer datatype, but when i create the above array with int datatype, it doesn't work properly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int a[] = {'a','p','p','l','e'};

    printf("%d\n",strlen(a));
    printf("%s\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code output is

> ```
> 1
> a
> ```

Why it consider only the first element of the array?

Comment: Second example is incorrect. Because char is one byte int usually 4 bytes.

Comment: C strings must be null-terminated. Your code invokes UB

Comment: @Vencat Are you getting any warning message(s) when compiling second example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String is longer than expected in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707486/string-is-longer-than-expected-in-c)

Comment: @purec there's no such thing as "default state of memory". [Using an uninitialized variable invokes undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11962457/995714)

Comment: Why? When you turn on your computer.

Comment: other duplicates: [What happened when we do not include '\0' at the end of string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34995106/995714), [why printf works on non-terminated string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4999901/995714). @purec turning on the PC != starting your process. There are tons of other things stored at that memory region before you store your variables there. Did you even bother to read the link?

Comment: phuclv, there is no even such thing as process at this stage.

Comment: @purec your C program is a process in an OS. Where do you think stdio writes to without a console? Read more and learn more. Even if you write a firmware like BIOS that starts before anything then there may be static charges on memory, which results in random values and programs must zero them out explicitly. And learn how to use this site, without `@` there would be no notification

Comment: @phuclv In the above question he got an error while running his code without '\0' , but in my case i didn't get any error.

Comment: I am just answering his question "How it is possible?" And I am saying that unused memory holds zeros. I am not a pastor to curse him with UB or other scary things.

Comment: @Vencat UB means anything can happen, including [*"making demons fly out of your nose"*](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). See the questions I linked above. [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first half of your question is equivalent to this:

> I'm new to life and started to learn about road traffic a few weeks back. I have read in a book that you should wait for the green light before entering the intersection, but when I enter the intersection without waiting, it works properly. How is it possible?

In other words, you just got lucky.  It just so happened that, even though you constructed an array of characters without a proper `\0` terminator, there happened to be a 0 byte in memory just after the `e` in `apple`, so it worked anyway.  But it's not at all guaranteed to work, any more than it's guaranteed that you can keep crossing the street against the light and not, eventually, get hit.

Moving on to your second question, when you read that "`char` is a subset of integer datatype", that does not at all mean that anywhere you would ordinarily use a `char`, you can also use `int`.

Here are some characters in memory.  Each of them is one byte in size:

```
char c1 = 'p', c1 = 'e', c3 = 'a', c4 = 'r';

    +---+                   +---+
c1: | p |               c2: | e |
    +---+                   +---+

    +---+                   +---+
c3: | a |               c4: | r |
    +---+                   +---+
```

Here are some ints in memory.  On a modern machine, each of them is probably four bytes in size:

```
int i1 = 'p', i1 = 'e', i3 = 'a', i4 = 'r';

    +---+---+---+---+       +---+---+---+---+
i1: | p             |   i2: | e             |
    +---+---+---+---+       +---+---+---+---+

    +---+---+---+---+       +---+---+---+---+
i3: | a             |   i4: | r             |
    +---+---+---+---+       +---+---+---+---+
```

Here is an array of `char`, properly null-terminated:

```
char ca[] = { 'p', 'e', 'a', 'r', '\0' };

    +---+---+---+---+---+
ca: | p | e | a | r |\0 |
    +---+---+---+---+---+
```

When `printf` prints this string, or `strlen` computes its length, they start at the beginning and move along the string one byte at a time, until they find the `\0`.

But here is an array of `int`:

```
int ia[] = { 'p', 'e', 'a', 'r', '\0' };

    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
ia: | p             | e             | a             | r             | \0            |
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

But I've drawn it slightly wrongly, because in reality, the three extra bytes in each int aren't filled with empty spaces, they're filled with zero bytes.  (It's as if we want to represent the number 1 with leading zeroes, that is, as 0001.)  So the more accurate picture looks like this;

```
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
ia: | p  \0  \0  \0 | e  \0  \0  \0 | a  \0  \0  \0 | r  \0  \0  \0 | \0  \0  \0  \0|
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

So when `printf` or `strlen` start at the beginning and process the array one byte at a time looking for the terminating `\0`, they find one immediately, just after the first letter.

An important point to consider here is that *`printf` and `strlen` are defined to operate on arrays of `char`*.  And because of the way C works, they had no way of knowing that you had cheated and passed an array of `int` instead.  They literally took that same memory and treated it as if it were an array of `char`, and so got a very different result than what you expected.

Because it's easy to make mistakes like this, good compilers will warn you if you do.  For your code, my compiler gave me these warnings:

```
warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int [5]' to parameter of type 'const char *'
warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'int *'
```

Those messages refer to type `char *`, which is pointer-to-`char`, because when you pass an array to a function, what actually gets passed is a pointer to the array's first element.  (But that's a topic for another day.  But it has a lot to do with what I said about `printf` and `strlen` "literally taking that same memory and treated it as if" it were an array of characters, instead.)

Comment: Good point. I fully oversaw that an array of 5 char's lacks a terminator what in turn is stricly necessary for `strlen()`.

Answer (score 2):

In `char a[] = {'a','p','p','l','e'};`, the compiler counts the number of values you provide, which is five. Then it creates an array of five `char` and initializes them with those values.

Then, in `printf("%d\n",strlen(a));` and in `printf("%s\n",a);`, the behavior is not defined by the C standard because you are required to have a zero element in the array to indicate where the end is. In the situation where you tried this, it may have happened that the memory after the `a` array contained a zero, resulting in the program printing “5” and “apple”. However, this will not always happen.

Additionally, the result of `strlen` has type `size_t` and ought to be printed with `%zu` rather than `%d`.

In `int a[] = {'a','p','p','l','e'};`, the compiler creates an array of `int`. When you use this in `printf("%s\n",a);`, you are passing a pointer to `int` when `printf` expects a pointer to `char`. The behavior of this is not defined by the C standard. A common result is that `printf` will process the bytes in the array of `int` as if they were an array of `char`, although this cannot be relied on—the actual behavior of C implementations may vary.

Since `int` are wider than `char`, an `int` containing the value `a` typically contains one byte with the value `a` and one or more bytes with the value zero. It may also contain padding bits. The order of the bytes within an `int` is not defined by the C standard. If the byte containing `a` happens to be first in memory, and the following bytes are zero, `printf` may print “a”. However, if a byte containing zero is first, `printf` will see that as the end of the string and will print nothing.

Again, the behavior is not defined by the C standard. The above only explains how what you saw may have come to be printed, not what you can expect in other situations.

Answer (score 1):

Passing an `int[]` to `strlen()` is wrong. `strlen()` expects characters. Even if you provide something else (and switch off or ignore all alerting warnings of compiler), `strlen()` interpretes the given address as `char*` (whatever it really contains).

To be strict, this is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939).

Investigating a little bit, we can explore what probably happens:

`char a[] = {'a','p','p','l','e'};`

defines an array of 5 characters. Dumped from memory this might look so:

```
0x61 0x70 0x70 0x6c 0x65 ???? ???? ????
```

`int a[] = {'a','p','p','l','e'};`, assuming 32 bit `int`, little endian, this might look so:

```
0x61 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x70 0x00 0x00 0x00
0x70 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x6c 0x00 0x00 0x00
0x65 0x00 0x00 0x00 ???? ???? ???? ????
```

Re-interpreting `a[]` as `char*` (what `strlen()` would do), this results in a string of length one.

However, it's still undefined behavior...

Answer (score 1):

Depends in the hardware and the implementation the `int` can be 2+ bytes long.

On the little endian system the first byte will be the ASCII code of 'a' and the second byte (and the consecutive up to sizeof(int)) zero. So the any string functions will consider it as single character string.

Big endian system will have the opposite byte order and if we interpret this int arrar as a char array the first character will be zero which terminates the string and the length of it will be zero.

Your second example is wrong  as you do not have a terminating zero and using it as a sting invokes the UB.

your char table initialization should be:

```
char a[] = {'a','p','p','l','e', 0};
```

or

```
char a[] = "apple";
```

as string literal initialization adds the terminating nul as well.

Comment: Oh good, someone mentioned endianness rather than assuming little-endian

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b most of OP users will never even see the big endian system :)

Answer (score 0):

On 32-bit compiler `int` takes 4 bytes and `char` takes 1 byte.
If you pass integer array to `strlen`, it scan first byte from integer which is `a` in your case, next
3 bytes are 0, hence `strlen` stops at second byte and shows `length` as `1`.

Comment: The widths of `int` and other types are more complicated than just whether a compiler is “32-bit”, “64-bit” or something else. One should not expect that a “32-bit compiler” necessarily has particular widths for its various integer types.

Answer (score 0):

> I have read in a book that character array should end with `\0`...

It is required only when you want to interpret the character array as string. In C language, strings are actually one-dimensional array of characters terminated by a null character `\0`.

In your first example, the `char` array `a` is simply array of characters. You are lucky that `strlen` and `printf` have given the expected output. The `strlen` function returns the number of characters that precede the terminating null character. In you case the memory just after the array `a` must be `0`. Hence, you are getting the expected output from `strlen`. For the same reason the `printf` is also working as expected because it writes every byte up to and not including the first null terminator.

In your second example, you are passing an integer pointer to `strlen`:

```
printf("%d\n",strlen(a));
```

Compiler must be giving warning message on it because the parameter type of `strlen` is `const char *` and you are passing it `int *`.

Also, in the `printf` you are giving argument as integer pointer. The `%s` format specifier expect a `char` pointer. The behavior is undefined in this case.